# How can I use the request object in a nested promise?

Tags: javascript, express, promise, callback

I am working on a Nuxt server side rendered application with the express framework. For authentication I am using the openid-client package. Now I want to store my retrieved token in the express session but the request model (req) is always undefined in the callback promise. To do this I want to use req.session.token = tokenSet.access_token. I am a Newbie in JavaScript so I think I am missing something obvious.

I tried various options on how to pass variables into a JavaScript promise but all of these required that you define the Promise by yourself which is not my case. I also tried waiting on the promise and using it outside of the callback promise but had no success either.

```js
router.get('/api/oidc-callback', (req, res, params) => {
  Issuer.discover('http://localhost:5000') // => Promise
    .then(function(identityIssuer) {
      const client = new identityIssuer.Client({
      ...
      })
      // HERE IT IS DEFINED
      console.log(req)
      client
        .callback('http://localhost:3000/api/oidc-callback', req.query, {
          code_verifier
        })
        // => Promise
        .then(function(tokenSet) {
          // HERE IT IS UNDEFINED
          console.log(req)
          req.session.token = tokenSet.access_token
        }, req)
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
//Also tried using outside
      res.redirect('/oidc-callback')
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It didn't disappear and is in scope inside that then() so seems more like you are misinterpreting the problem

Comment: I believe the reason why `req` is undefined because the promise was resolved after the execution of the middleware `(res, req, next) =>{...}`. Try returning the top level promise i.e. `(res, req, next) =>{ return  Issuer.discover(...)}`, also add a `return` statement before  `client.callback(..)`. Let me know it works.

Comment: You need to delete `, req` from the inner then's parameter list. Only an error handler (Function) should appear in that position. May not fix the issue but won't hurt.

Comment: @macphilips adding the return statements worked, makes more sense now! Thank you

Comment: @nils168 You are welcome. I'm going to extract my comment as an answer to this question and accept it as the correct answer

Comment: @macphilips The variable cannot magically become `undefined` just because the execution of the middleware ended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two nested asynchronous operations (shown simplified here) and then you try to do something last in the first `.then()` handler:

```
Issuer.discover().then(function() {
    client.callback().then(function() {
       // ...
    });
    res.redirect('/oidc-callback');
});
```

This causes `res.redirect()` to get called before `client.callback()` is done as there is nothing in your code that make it wait for the completion of `client.callback()`.  That sends the response and triggers a redirect before you modify the session which is not what you want to do.  You can fix that in one of two ways:

1) Put the `res.redirect()` inside the inner `.then()` like this:

```
Issuer.discover().then(function() {
    client.callback().then(function() {
       // ...
       res.redirect('/oidc-callback');
    });
});
```

2) Add a `return` before `client.callback()` so that it will chain the inner promise to the outer one.  Then, the outer one won't finish until the inner one is done and  you can add another `.then()` handler to put the `res.redirect()` into:

```
Issuer.discover().then(function() {
    return client.callback().then(function() {
       // ...
    });
```

}).then(function() {
        // gets called when both asynchronous operations are done
        res.redirect('/oidc-callback');
   });

I'd recommend option #2 because it makes error handling simpler as you can do all your error handling in one place at the top level.  Putting all that together, you'd end up with this:

```
router.get('/api/oidc-callback', (req, res, params) => {
    Issuer.discover('http://localhost:5000').then(function(identityIssuer) {
        const client = new identityIssuer.Client({
            ...
        })
        return client.callback('http://localhost:3000/api/oidc-callback', req.query, {
            code_verifier
        }).then(function(tokenSet) {
            console.log(req);
            req.session.token = tokenSet.access_token
        }, req);
    }).then(() => {
        res.redirect('/oidc-callback');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

Note, I also added proper error handling at the end.  This makes sure that no response is sent until both your async operations are done and if either one fails, it sends a proper error response.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why req is undefined because the promise was resolved after the execution of the middleware (res, req, next) =>{...}. Try returning the top level promise i.e. (res, req, next) =>{ return Issuer.discover(...)}, also add a return statement before client.callback(...).

```
router.get('/api/oidc-callback', (req, res, params) => {
  return Issuer.discover('http://localhost:5000') // <-- added return here
    .then(function(identityIssuer) {
      const client = new identityIssuer.Client({
      ...
      })
      // HERE IT IS DEFINED
      console.log(req)
      return client  // <-- added return here
        .callback('http://localhost:3000/api/oidc-callback', req.query, {
          code_verifier
        })
        // => Promise
        .then(function(tokenSet) {
          // HERE IT IS UNDEFINED
          console.log(req)
          req.session.token = tokenSet.access_token
          res.redirect('/oidc-callback')
        }) // removed , req here, it is not needed
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    })
})
```

By adding the return statement, it tells express you are running an async function, thus express it going to wait until your middleware is resolved before moving on to the next middleware.

Comment: This will not work at all.  You've put the `res.redirect()` in the same function after a `return` statement.  It will never get executed.  You were on the right path by adding `return` in front of `return client.callback()`, but other changes have to be made to work properly with that so the rest of the answer is incorrect.  You can see my answer below for a complete explanation and for revised code that should work.